# Table: align comma-separated pairs of numbers on comma

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, alignment

I have a table where entries are two (rational/integer) numbers separated by a comma. Is it possible in each column to (a) keep the column labels $L$, $M$, and $R$ centered and (b) align the entries so that the commas are aligned?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
  \begin{tabular}{c|ccc|}
       \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$L$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$M$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$R$} \\ \cline{2-4}
       $T$                  & $-1, \frac{3}{5}$       & $3,4$                   & $0,-1$                  \\
       $B$                  & $1,-8$                  & $2,-4$                  & $0,1$                   \\ \cline{2-4}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [dcolumn](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/dcolumn) package is your friend.

[image]

*Addendum*: In the code used here, no whitespace padding is inserted around the commas. If do you want the commas to be surrounded by, say, `\thinspace` (aka `\,`), just change `\newcolumntype{C}{D{,}{,}{2.2}}` to `\newcolumntype{C}{D{,}{\,,\,}{2.2}}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn}        % for 'D' column type
\newcolumntype{C}{D{,}{,}{2.2}} % center cell contents on commas
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
  $\begin{array}{c|CCC|}
  \mc{} & \mc{L} & \mc{M} & \mc{R} \\ 
  \cline{2-4}
    T & -1, \frac{3}{5} & 3,4  & 0,-1  \\
    B & 1,-8            & 2,-4 & 0,1   \\ 
  \cline{2-4}
  \end{array}$
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Reminder to myself: the third option {2.2} means "two digits to the left, to digits to the right of the separator".

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure, that there is a better way than this solution. I used a separate column for each number and the comma. By choosing `rcl` alignment and adjusting the spacing for the columns, you can achieve the desired effect.

I used the `tblr` environment from `tabularray` package, since it greatly simplifies the commands for setting the correct spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tblr}{
            colspec={c*{3}{rcl}}, cells={mode=math},
            vline{2,Z}={2-Z}{solid}, hline{2,Z}={2-Z}{solid},
            column{2,5,8}={rightsep=0pt},
            column{3,6,9}={colsep=0pt},
            column{4,7,10}={leftsep=0pt},
        }
        & \SetCell[c=3]{c} L &&& \SetCell[c=3]{c} M &&& \SetCell[c=3]{c} R && \\
        T & -1 & , & \frac{3}{5} & 3 & , & 4  & 0 & , & -1 \\
        B & 1  & , & -8          & 2 & , & -4 & 0 & , & 1  \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: table]

Regarding your row spacing, `tblr` has more vertical spacing by default. You can adjust this if you like, e.g. with `rowsep=4pt` (default `2pt`)  in the argument of `\begin{tblr}`.

Answer (score 3):

Use a custom table preamble, here I use a separator `,\,` between `r` and `l` columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}


$\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\begin{array}{ c | *{3}{r @{,\,} l}|}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{L} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{M} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{R} \\
\cline{2-7}
T & -1 & \frac{3}{5} & 3 &  4 & 0 & -1 \\
B &  1 & -8          & 2 & -4 & 0 &  1 \\
\cline{2-7}
\end{array}$

\end{document}
```

[image]